# Change a PHP variable/value via form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to change some values on my html page, like my community name. I input the value and click on the submit button. I want that little button to change the variable's values according to what I changed it to on the form (If that makes sense).

If it helps, I am using Bootstrap (latest version).

#### config.php

```
$communityName = "My Community";
$communityLinks = array("Home", "Store", "Forum");
```

#### functionality.php

```
if (isset($_POST['communityName'])) {
   $communityName = ($_POST['communityName']);
}
if (isset($_POST['communityLinks'])) {
   $communityLinks = str_replace("\r\n", '","',($_POST['communityLinks']));
}
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
include ("functionality.php");
?>
<div id="accordion" class="container">
    <div class="card b-light-shadow">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="accord-btn btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Basics
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Community Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1" name="communityName" placeholder="Community Name" value="<?= $communityName ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Community Lins</label>
                        <p class="form-description">Change your links here.</p>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="communityLinks" type="text"><?php $i = 0; $len = count($communityLinks); foreach ($communityLinks as $cL) { echo $cL; if ($i != $len - 1) { echo "&#013;"; } $i++;  } ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3em;">
        <div class="container">
           <button class="subm-btn btn btn-link" type="submit" name="action">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$communityLinks = str_replace(` will make a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Put your submit button inside form. For now it makes nothing.

Comment: I added <form action="" method="post"> right above the first div (basically the entire document). Still no results.

Comment: @TylerShannon I'm not sure you did it correctly. Actually I run your code locally and it works with submit inside of form. Except php warning due to error mentioned in comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pretty close.  However, you aren't using your `$communityName` to display in your HTML code.

to get that going, just replace this:

```
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Community Name</label>
```

with this:

```
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><?= $communityName ?></label>
```

Now, if you successfully post to this page, the name should change.

Next, as @user3783243 mentioned. `str_replace` is going to give you a string,  but you are using `$communityLinks` as an array, so you need an array of links.  You should use the **[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** function to get an array from your user input.

Something like this could work:

```
$communityLinks = explode("\r\n", $_POST['communityName']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My issue still has not been fixed though.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for the long reply. But after some more digging, I managed to figure it out, it was a very rookie mistake. Thanks for your help.